# Retrieve stored checkbox value from sql server database to re-enable it

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, checkbox

I have checkbox value in the gridview which is bound to item template in this manner:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxDisable" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxDisableEvent"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And i'm implementing the **CheckBoxDisableEvent** method in this manner which does nothing but store the checkbox checked value into sql server table.

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertDisableFlagIntoComponents", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@disableFlag", SqlDbType.Int).Value = disableFlag;
```

Now the problem is when the gridview loads on the start of the project next time, i want to enable all those checkboxes depending upon the value that i have stored in database during previous events.

How can i enable the checkbox values in gridview depending on the values that i stored in sql server table.

BTW i'm using vs2008 with asp.net/C#, sqlserver 2005

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("ColumnName") == true ? false : true %>'  />
```

Comment: @Muhammad can you please explain what you have written ?? Thanks in anticipation

Comment: If your DB column is true, then checkbox will be disable and you can't uncheck it.

Comment: @Muhammad i want the column to be checked if it is unchecked and unchecked if it is checked. The only thing i want is depending on the value that is stored in the database i want it to be either checked or unchecked. And more over i'm storing the data in the form of 1 and 0, 1-checkbox enabled and 0-checkbox-disabled (which is default). And it is giving me error when i use your code in my project.

Comment: Edited, try now and let me know.

Comment: @Muhammad at last it is done !! The mistake i'm doing is  using the stored procedure to retrieve the values from the database table. In the stored procedure i'm not retrieving the flag value, and i was only changing table field values and it was just giving me an error that disableflag is a unknown field. At last i figured it out. Thats the reason it took such a long time to respond. Thanks Muhammad !! It was of great help. Truly appreciate it !!

Comment: @Muhammad now i'm facing another problem which i have not noticed previously, i'm not able to uncheck the "checked" checkbox. If i uncheck it, it is again checking it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxDisable" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ColumnName")) ? true : false %>' Checked='<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>' />
```

Comment: which column name should i specify in the code given ? Is it the database fieldname in the sqlserver or the data field name in the gridview ?